# shadowRadius can not set higher

Tags: ios, calayer

I am setting `shadowRadius`, but after around 3 it has no visual effect it would increase the radius of the shadow, why?

```
self.vcLeft.btn.shadowRadius = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow offset prevents it. **By default it's (0, -3):**

```
 /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (0, -3). Animatable. */

    open var shadowOffset: CGSize
```

**So, just do that.** And then play around with values of `shadowRadius`.

```
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```